# Как отследить из aiohttp.web.WebSocket, что клиент уже отключился?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, aiohttp

Как определить со стороны сервера, что WebSocket клиент уже от него отключился (приложение закрыли)?

У меня есть такой код клиента:

```
import asyncio
import os

import aiohttp.web

HOST = os.getenv('HOST', '127.0.0.1')
PORT = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8881))


async def testhandle(request):
    print("server: into testhandle()")
    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='Test handle')



async def websocket_handler(request):
    print('Websocket connection starting')
    ws = aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    print('Websocket connection ready')

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            #print(msg.data)
            if msg.data == 'close':
                await ws.close()
            else:
                await ws.send_str("You said: {}".format(msg.data))
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
            print('ws connection closed with exception %s' %
                  ws.exception())     


    print('Websocket connection closed')
    return ws


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = aiohttp.web.Application(loop=loop)
    app.add_routes([aiohttp.web.get('/', websocket_handler), 
                    aiohttp.web.get('/test', testhandle)])
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host=HOST, port=PORT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

И сервер никогда не завершает свою работу, пока не получит "close" от клиента.
Но я бы хотел, чтобы сервер выводил когда клиент отключился...
В `tornado` это делалось примерно так:

```
    msg = await self.ws.read_message()
    if msg is None:
        print_with_preampula ("connection closed")
        self.ws = None
        break
```

A в `aiohttp` что то не могу этого добиться. Подкажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: У вас не выводится 'Websocket connection closed' когда клиент отключается?

Comment: Если я пошлю "close", то может быть и выключится.... Но когда я просто закрываю клиента, то точно не выводися. А хотелось бы. В этот и вопрос

Comment: Странно, должно выводиться. Я на всякий случай даже у себя проверил, выводится.

Comment: PS C:\workspace_ilya\sandbox> python .\tornado_server_2.py
 .\tornado_server_2.py:45: DeprecationWarning: loop argument is deprecated
   app = aiohttp.web.Application(loop=loop)
 ======== Running on http://127.0.0.1:8881 ========
 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 Websocket connection starting
 Websocket connection ready
 Websocket connection starting
 Websocket connection ready

Comment: НЕ пишет сообщение от том что клиент отвалился к сожалению.....